# React Hook Form dynamic required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-hook-form

I'm trying to make a form with two fields using react hook form where the required value of the text field depends on the value of the select drop down.

Here is my code:

```
  const { handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

  const [isPickupPoint, togglePickupPoint] = useState(false);

  const handleDestinationTypeChange: EventFunction = ([selected]) => {
    togglePickupPoint(selected.value === "PICKUP_POINT");
    return selected;
  };
```

```
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <InputLabel>Destination type</InputLabel>
              <Controller
                as={Select}
                name="destinationType"
                control={control}
                options={[
                  { label: "Pickup point", value: "PICKUP_POINT" },
                  { label: "Shop", value: "SHOP" },
                ]}
                rules={{ required: true }}
                onChange={handleDestinationTypeChange}
              />
              {errors.destinationType && (
                <ErrorLabel>This field is required</ErrorLabel>
              )}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Controller
                as={
                  <TextField
                    label="Pickup Point ID"
                    fullWidth={true}
                    disabled={!isPickupPoint}
                  />
                }
                control={control}
                name="pickupPointId"
                rules={{ required: isPickupPoint }}
              />
              {errors.pickupPointId && (
                <ErrorLabel>This field is required</ErrorLabel>
              )}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Button
                onClick={onSubmit}
                variant={"contained"}
                color={"primary"}
                type="submit"
              >
                Save
              </Button>
            </Grid>
```

The `isPickupPoint` flag changes properly because the `disabled` prop of the `textfield` works fine. Only when the PICKUP_POINT option is selected the text field is active. But the required prop is not working, it is always false. When I try submitting the form when its empty the `destinationType` error label appears, but when I try to submit the form with the PICKUP_POINT option and empty `pickupPointId` field it passes with no errors.

How can I make this dynamic required prop work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code here, it looks like `isPickUpPoint` is working as expected since it works for disable. Since you are using the same property for required, it should flow through. I would suspect that the bug may lie in your `Controller` component. I would take a look there and make sure that the property is what you expected to be.

Also for disabled the condition is `!isPickUpPoint`, so it will trigger when it's false.

For required the condition is `isPickUpPoint` so it will trigger when it's true.

That's also a bit of a disconnect since it looks like it's the same input.

Comment: The `Controller` component is a react-hooks-form component actually so not much I can do there I'm afraid. Unless there is something I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hmm, what about the miss-match between disabled and required? Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, if the PICKUP_POINT option is chosen the field should be enabled (hence !isPickupPoint - the field should be disabled if the PICKUP_POINT isn't chose).  And when the field is enabled, it should be required.